# How to average hourly interval data for a 12 hour range in SQL Server from 8am to 8pm given daily hourly data?

Tags: sql, sql-server, datetime, where-clause

I have hourly interval data in my DB in the following format:

```
EFFECTIVEDATETIME       NEW_YORK ETC...                
---------------------------------------
2017-01-01 01:00:00.000 44
2017-01-01 02:00:00.000 44
2017-01-01 03:00:00.000 45
2017-01-01 04:00:00.000 44
2017-01-01 05:00:00.000 45
2017-01-01 06:00:00.000 44
2017-01-01 07:00:00.000 44
2017-01-01 08:00:00.000 44
2017-01-01 09:00:00.000 44
2017-01-01 10:00:00.000 46
2017-01-01 11:00:00.000 45
2017-01-01 12:00:00.000 46
2017-01-01 13:00:00.000 47
2017-01-01 14:00:00.000 47
2017-01-01 15:00:00.000 47
2017-01-01 16:00:00.000 47
2017-01-01 17:00:00.000 46
2017-01-01 18:00:00.000 45
2017-01-01 19:00:00.000 43
2017-01-01 20:00:00.000 41
2017-01-01 21:00:00.000 42
2017-01-01 22:00:00.000 42
2017-01-01 23:00:00.000 41
```

I was trying to average the New York and following columns for only a specific range, from 08:00:00.000 to 20:00:000. I was able to do it for the entire day with the following code. However would prefer being able to average my data for only that 12 hour period. Any help would be appreciated, thanks!

```
SELECT 
    CAST(EFFECTIVEDATETIME AS DATE) AS EFFECTIVE_DATE,
    AVG(CASE WHEN WEATHERSTATIONID = 'KNYC' THEN TEMPERATURE ELSE NULL END) AS NEW_YORK,
    AVG(CASE WHEN WEATHERSTATIONID = 'KNYC' THEN DEWPOINT ELSE NULL END) AS NEW_YORK_DEWPOINT,
    AVG(CASE WHEN WEATHERSTATIONID = 'KNYC' THEN RelativeHumidity ELSE NULL END) AS NEW_YORK_HUMIDITY,
    MAX(CASE WHEN WEATHERSTATIONID = 'KNYC' THEN TEMPERATURE ELSE NULL END) AS NEW_YORK_DAILY_MAX,
    MIN(CASE WHEN WEATHERSTATIONID = 'KNYC' THEN TEMPERATURE ELSE NULL END)  AS NEW_YORK_DAILY_MIN
FROM
    DBO.WeatherHourly
WHERE
    EffectiveDateTime > '2017-01-01'
GROUP BY 
    CAST(EFFECTIVEDATETIME AS DATE)
ORDER BY 
    EFFECTIVE_DATE
```

Comment: I removed the inconsistent database tags.  Please tag only with the database youa re really using.

Comment: Not 100% clear, but seems if you add the time check on effectiveDateTime to only include hours between 8 and 20, you should get what you want

Answer (score 1):

If you want to limit the start time to the interval, you can use:

```
WHERE EffectiveDateTime > '2017-01-01' AND
      CAST(EffectiveDateTime as TIME) BETWEEN '08:00:00' AND '20:00:00'
```

If you want a limit on the end date/time as well, that is a bit more challenging.

Comment: Thank you brother- apologizes about the tag earlier!

Answer (score 0):

You could just add a filter condition on the hour of the day in the `WHERE` clause:

```
SELECT CAST(EFFECTIVEDATETIME AS DATE) AS EFFECTIVE_DATE,
    AVG(CASE WHEN WEATHERSTATIONID = 'KNYC' THEN TEMPERATURE ELSE NULL END) AS NEW_YORK,
    AVG(CASE WHEN WEATHERSTATIONID = 'KNYC' THEN DEWPOINT ELSE NULL END) AS NEW_YORK_DEWPOINT,
    AVG(CASE WHEN WEATHERSTATIONID = 'KNYC' THEN RelativeHumidity ELSE NULL END) AS NEW_YORK_HUMIDITY,
    MAX(CASE WHEN WEATHERSTATIONID = 'KNYC' THEN TEMPERATURE ELSE NULL END) AS NEW_YORK_DAILY_MAX,
    MIN(CASE WHEN WEATHERSTATIONID = 'KNYC' THEN TEMPERATURE ELSE NULL END)  AS NEW_YORK_DAILY_MIN
FROM DBO.WeatherHourly
WHERE EffectiveDateTime > '2017-01-01' AND DATEPART(hour, EffectiveDateTime) BETWEEN 8 AND 19
GROUP BY CAST(EFFECTIVEDATETIME AS DATE)
ORDER BY EFFECTIVE_DATE
```

Comment: Thank you! Didn't know you could add an and statement and filter it that way